# Can I cycle through instances of a style selected via the MS Word styles pane?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, styles

Often when I have many co-authors on a MS Word document (versions up to and inc. Word 2007) I find that some of them don't use the styles I've defined for the document, but have achieved similar formatting manually.  This results in many styles listed as "in use", each with perhaps only a handful of instances.  Word will highlight these instances for me, but then find myself browsing the entire document to check whether they need correcting or are special cases. This can be a particular pain for a long document and when these style fragments occur in the white space between words or paragraphs.

Is there a way to cycle through the highlighted instances of a particular style rather than having to hunt for them visually?

Comment: I've had this nightmare during every group project in college...

Comment: In 2007, the first option doesn't work because the Style box in the Find window only has the basic built-in styles but none of the variations we're trying to get through. Re option 2, 2007 is ribbon based and I can't think of the equivalent of this workaround for 2007.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things that can help you. You don't mention which version of Word you're using. This answer is for 2003, but the same features should be available in 2007 and 2010.

First, if you go to Edit --> Find, select the "More" button, and then select the "Format" button. Under "Format", you'll find "Style". You can select the style you want it to search for.

Second, you can display the style pane. Go to Tools menu --> Options --> View Tab and all the way at the bottom you'll see "Style Area Width" and set it to about 1".

In the 2003 version you'll have to be in "Normal" view to see the style pane.

Comment: Sounds logical - I'm surprised I didn't try that first suggestion before.  I'll give it a go when I get back to a PC after Easter.  Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. Let me know if it works.